# How to create a true type font (.ttf) font from CAD-designed letters?

Tags: fonts, font-design, font-forge, autocad, ttf

I need to create a true type (.ttf) font, in order to use in different programs without the need to convert the font every time.

So I designed an alphabet using AutoCAD and now I want to create the font. I tried several programs such as FontForge, but none of them allowed me to load a "pre-designed" letter.

**How do I go about creating a font file from single letters designed in CAD?**

Answer (score 1):

This depends, on the way you made the fonts.

Font forge can load your letters, but you need to export them in a format that it can read. I suggest using EPS, although SVG can also work out fine. You need to export each letter separately.  You can make the process faster if you save each letter in a file named uni####.eps where the #### is a Unicode code for the letter. You can then load things in as a EPS template and don't need to load each letter separately.

Now, if your font is made out of pure lines, that do not form a closed area. Then most applications can not use the font as is. You need to make it such that each letter is closed. You can either do this in autocad or FontForge.

Now if you want a font native to autocad called made out of lines called SHX. I suggest you do this for line fonts. Then read [this](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/autocad-forum/how-make-shx-font-file/td-p/2025099) I will try it and test it later.